# Questions about bitwise one complement operator (Java)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

When I am studying bitwise one complement operator, I see some examples on the internet:

(in short)
Example 1:

int a= 15;
int b = 27;

//15 = 0000 1111
//27 = 0001 1011

The result of ~ a is -16
//-16= 0001 0000

From: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfH2Fkc1ujg

If ~ is to convert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 , why putting 0001 0000 and the result is -16?

Example 2:

Bitwise Not or Complement operator simply means the negation of each bit of the input value. It takes only one integer and it's equivalent to the ! operator.

This operator changes each binary digit of the integer, which means all 0 become 1 and all 1 become 0. The ! operator works similarly for boolean values: it reverses boolean values from true to false and vice versa.

Now let's understand with an example how to find the complement of a decimal number.

Let's do the complement of value1 = 6:

```
  @Test
  public void givenOneInteger_whenNotOperator_thenNewDecimalNumber() {
  int value1 = 6;
 int result = ~value1;
 assertEquals(-7, result);
     }
```

The value in binary is:

value1 = 0000 0110
By applying the complement operator, the result will be:
0000 0110 -> 1111 1001
This is the one’s complement of the decimal number 6. And since the first (leftmost) bit is 1 in binary, it means that the sign is negative for the number that is stored.

Now, since the numbers are stored as 2’s complement, first we need to find its 2’s complement and then convert the resultant binary number into a decimal number:

1111 1001 -> 0000 0110 + 1 -> 0000 0111
Finally, 0000 0111 is 7 in decimal. Since the sign bit was 1 as mentioned above, therefore the resulting answer is:

result : -7

From: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bitwise-operators#4-bitwisecomplement-

Why are the results negative?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

"Now, since the numbers are stored as 2’s complement, first we need to find its 2’s complement..." No.  You're complementing too many times.  You're *just* computing 1111 1001's value in binary, and that's -7.

In general, it is always the case that `~x == -x - 1`.  You can also use that to calculate the value of negative two's complement values: `-x == ~x + 1`, which is why you got 7: `x` is -7.